# How to delete rows for column having Non-NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input Dataframe(df)

```
Country Region      Date    Value.....
ABW     NaN     01-01-2020  123
ABW     NaN     02-01-2020  1234
ABW     NaN     03-01-2020  3242
USA     NaN     04-01-2020  4354
USA     NaN     05-01-2020  43543
USA     NaN     06-01-2020  34534
USA     NaN     07-01-2020  435
USA     WA      08-01-2020  43345
USA     WA      09-01-2020  345
USA     WV      10-01-2020  345
.
.
.
.
```

Expected Output(df1)

```
Country Region      Date    Value.....
ABW     NaN     01-01-2020  123
ABW     NaN     02-01-2020  1234
ABW     NaN     03-01-2020  3242
USA     NaN     04-01-2020  4354
USA     NaN     05-01-2020  43543
USA     NaN     06-01-2020  34534
USA     NaN     07-01-2020  435
.
.
.
.
```

So from the above dataframe you can see that the column '`Region`' has NaN as well as non-null values, I'd like to remove the entire row where column '`Region`' has non-NaN values.

Also, AFTER performing the above operation, if I wanted to entirely remove the `Region` column, how to do that in the fastest possible way(10k+ columns)?? Experts, please help!

FINAL Expected Output

```
Country         Date        Value.....
ABW             01-01-2020  123
ABW             02-01-2020  1234
ABW             03-01-2020  3242
USA             04-01-2020  4354
USA             05-01-2020  43543
USA             06-01-2020  34534
USA             07-01-2020  435
```

Here's the code I tried

```
df1=df1.isnull(df1['Region'])
```

Error

```
    df1=df.isnull(df['Region'])                                                                                                                                                          
TypeError: isnull() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: df = df[df.Region.isnull()]

Comment: Thanks!! @BEN_YO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @BEN_YO's suggestion, this is what I did, works fine

```
 filtered_df = df1[df1['Region'].isnull()]
```